# Is there a text-editor in GNU/Linux where CTRL++ for making font bigger works?

Tags: debian, editors

In GNU/Linux all the text editors I have used I have go to and make the font bigger size via going through the menu. Is there a text-editor where you can use or bind <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to zoom in and out.

Comment: I'm sure Emacs could be configured to recognize this keybinding, although it would not make sense to configure it that way.  Emacs key sequences tend to be more structured and logical.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010895/bind-key-to-increase-decrease-font-size-in-emacs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gedit, the default text editor for GNOME, can do that. But first you have to enable the Text Size plugin. It is shipped with the `gedit-plugins` package.

Comment: You can install the `gedit-plugin-text-size` plugin independently: `sudo apt-get install -y gedit-plugin-text-size`

Answer (score 2):

`Terminator` console is a very useful terminal where you can split until you have 'n' workspaces in the same Window.

The feature of pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> to change the font size works pretty good using vim editor for example.

Read more in [here](http://gnometerminator.blogspot.mx/p/introduction.html?m=1)

Comment: +1. You can also hold Ctrl and use the scroll wheel to change font size. And use nano/emacs/etc. too.

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs, you can put these lines in your init file:

```
(global-set-key [(control ?+)] 'text-scale-increase)
(global-set-key [(control ?-)] 'text-scale-decrease)
```

By default, the font size changing commands are in the menu that appears on <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Button1</kbd> (<kbd>Button1</kbd> is the left mouse button).

Answer (score 0):

Kate and kwrite allow this by default. You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll wheel</kbd> to zoom in and out.

Libreoffice won't let you bind keys, but you can use the scroll wheel as above.

If you use `gvim`, you could easily [bind keystrokes](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font) to zoom.